# How to contain div grid inside parent

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a horizontal grid for a portfolio.

[image]

So it's a grid stacking elements from top to bottom, and when it reaches 3 elements, goes back to the top to start a new column.

Is there a way to add the squares in the container, and when the squares go overflow, to stack them back up?

I'm stuck here > [test](http://pixel-salad.com/test/)

Comment: You could also use column-count. Inline-flex can also be a solution if you want to squeeze each col to previous. http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/pyBqpO (an extra pseudo to fill gap in last col to mimic the bg-color  unseen .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the container element a flex-box with the property `flex-flow:column wrap;`.

```css
#container {
  max-height: 700px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.square {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
  <div class="square">
    <p>1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>6</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>7</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>8</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>9</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>10</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>11</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>12</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>13</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>14</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>15</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>16</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>17</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>18</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>19</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square">
    <p>20</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Woswsk , i would go for flex, but inline-flex would be my choice to keep columns against each others:

I would also use a pseudo to fill any gap within the last col to mimic bg-color.

If you need bg-color to fill entire width, you'll need an extra wrapper to show it. Snippet below uses body to show the use of extra wrapper. In this case the pseudo has no purpose anymore..

```js
$(function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    $("#container").append("<div class='square'><p>" + (i + 1) + "</p></div>")
  }

});
```

```css
#container {
  max-height: 600px;
  /* test also 800 & 1300px to see pseudo behavior*/
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: blue;
}
#container:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
.square {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  border: solid 1px white;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* body used as extra wrapper for demo show */

html {
  background: white;
}
body {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="clearfix"></div>
```